# Ejecutar python desde xp_cmdshell en sql server

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo una version de sql server 2008, la cual no tiene las opciones de integrar python desde el instalador. Necesito ejecutar un archivo de python el cual hace scrapping a una websitie para extraer informacion y actualizarla a la base de datos, el archivo python ya lo tengo, mi idea esta en que cada vez que ingresan un registros mandar a ejecutar mediante un trigger de inserccion de python para que este haga scrapping y mande actualizar la informacion en la base de datos, segun los datos proporcionados.

Estuve investigando la ejecucion de python mediante xp_cmdshell pero dada la casualidad lo ejecuto y me indica que python no esta instalado, y realmente si lo he hecho, he averiguado que hay que hacerlo en la instancia de sql server, pero no se como hacerlo.

Podrían por favor alguien ayudarme, o si existe alguna otra manera que pueda realizar lo indicado.

---

[image: Error que indica que python no esta instalado]

Solo cuando hago uso desde el cmd de forma directa si me funciona pero desde el xp_cmdshell no, he realizado algunas pruebas y nada, pero lo que no he intentando es instalar python en la instancia de sql server, que eso no comprendo como hacerlo.

Comment: Verifica que py.exe esté en la ruta `C:\Windows`. Personalmente no me gusta ejecutar Python por ahí, pero debe funcionar. Si no se encuentra, posiblemente instalaste Python como usuario normal (no administrador). Reinstala Python como administrador, para todos los usuarios y en `C:\Python3xx`, agregar ruta al PATH de sistema. Reinicia las aplicaciones para que actualicen estas variables.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya voy a intentar.

Comment: He intentado de muchas maneras y no veo la forma en como ejecutar python de la forma explicada, por favor alguien tiene alguna idea adicional??

Comment: Ya lo he conseguido, en realidad la solución estaba en la desintalación del launcher de python en windows, luego de ellos segui el consejo del compañero, con lo que instale python para todos los usuarios y ahora si me ejecuta desde la instancia de sql, claro esta que las librerias adicionales tambien me toco instalarlas en dichas instancias, gracias de igual forma. Saludos.